# Azure Redis Cache statistic per cache key

Tags: azure, caching, redis

I wonder is there a way to get a redis cache key statistic in Azure by Appinsight azure.
For instance, i need to know a average number of access per second per key in Azure. I have checked this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/#how-to-view-metrics-and-customize-charts manual but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Per key metrics are not available on Azure, check what they can provide:

[Available metrics on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/#available-metrics-and-reporting-intervals)

Internally they use redis [INFO](http://redis.io/commands/info) command and to begin with, INFO doesn't provide that kind of detail.